# How to export to multiple sheets in excel from jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on a report with iReport that have many subreports.

I want to have two other sheets in the excel file when generating the report from my application.

When searching the internet I found answers about creating a break in the report, having the option "Ignore pagination " in the subreports "true" , but it is still not clear for me.

What are my options to control how and when a new sheet is created

Comment: Hello Petter ! Thanks for your answers :) Actually  i am using Jasper Report server . What i did is that i set net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet="true" , created a new group in which i put the subreport to be generated in the second sheet with the Group property : Start on a new page "checked".Also the property "ignore pagination" was checked in the subreport and the master report,And this worked ! I have put the content of the master report in the detail band.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In jasper report there are different ways to achieve new sheet both in `jrxml` and in `java` code. The default behavior is to create a new sheet for every page. I will illustrated the 3 most common ways with relative problem in using them.

> **Ignore pagination and break element**

**Method**

set `isIgnorePagination="true"` on the `jasperReport` tag and add

```
<break>
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="1" uuid="c5371aa4-2eb4-4ab9-8cae-39f50da3317b"/>
</break>
```

when you need a new sheet.

**Problem**: The report will not be beautiful if you export also to pdf (since its ignoring pagination)

> **Use the jrxml properties**

**Method**
To avoid creating new sheet on every new page, set property

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet="false"
```

And when you want it to create a new sheet before or after an `reportElement` add relative property:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row="true"
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row="true"
```

**Problem**: The columns on every sheet will be the same and this can result in ugly colspan on different sheet's

> **Use java and controll the sheet's as you like (loading different reports)**

**Method**

```
List<JasperPrint> sheets = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
for (int i=1;i<=8;i++){
   JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("subReport_" + i + ".jasper", paramMap, connection);
   sheets.add(print); 
}
JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(sheets));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File("text.xlxs"));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
configuration.setSheetNames(sheetNames): //sheets names is an array of the different names.
configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false); //remove that it break on new page
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

**Problem**: You can not use this method if you are using jasper report server.