# How to set dynamic main report width when using crosstab?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I am making a report that shows only a Crosstab with dynamic count of records.

This means that I will be needing to have a main report without a fixed width. Thus far, I seem to have no luck in a clean method (I just make the width super large, like over 10,000).

So is there some sort of build-it keyword for width like `DYNAMIC` or `hasNoWidth` so that the width of the main report will be based on the width of the Crosstab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single crosstab use the attribute `ignoreWidth="true"`

From [Schema reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#crosstab)

> If this attribute is set to true, the crosstab will expand towards the
>   right (or towards the left if the crosstab direction is RTL) as long
>   as it needs to. This would result in crosstab cells being rendered
>   over the page boundary; such elements will be exported by certain
>   grid-based exporters such as the HTML or XLS ones, but will not be
>   visible in export formats that observe the page width, such as the PDF
>   exporter.

**NOTE**: How this works for export where dynamic width is possible as HTML, XLS but not for export where dynamic width is not possible as PDF.

**Example**

```
<crosstab ignoreWidth="true">
    ....
</crosstab>
```

If you like **all** crosstab's in report to `ignoreWidth` you can also set property [net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.ignore.width](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.ignore.width)

**Example**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="48809477-2290-4dda-a6f9-5d348ff0b70b">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.ignore.width" value="true"/>
....
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Also I would like to know if you can make a config that doesn't cut the crosstab whenever it exceeds the page height. But I would understand if you wanted that to be at another question.

Comment: You do  not want it to be in new page?... it should continue? what is your export?

Comment: I don't since the report has to be continously be in one table only. I would say excel, I decided to just put the top and bottom margin of the pages to 0.

Comment: In jasper report you have an attribute isIgnorePagination="true" on the jasperReport tag... but you can also set when exporting.  You can check this for excel (its how to handle different sheets) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808741/how-to-export-to-multiple-sheets-in-excel-from-jasper-report