# java and jasperreport wrong xlsx output from server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm using *JasperReports* without *iReport*. I take XLSX output. 
On local and Server take different out put.

server output

[image]

local output

[image]

I want every table will be different page.

Server output in office 2013 change page format will be correct but I look 2 file server and local file both of letter format.

```
                    List<JasperReportBuilder> buildersList = (List<JasperReportBuilder>) builders.get(jasperReportBuilderHandler);

                for (int i = 0; i < buildersList.size(); i++) {
                    JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilder = buildersList.get(i);
                    jasperReportBuilder.setPageFooterPrintWhenExpression(new AbstractSimpleExpression<Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean evaluate(ReportParameters reportParameters) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    jasperReportBuilder.setIgnorePagination(true);
                    builder.add(DynamicReports.cmp.subreport(jasperReportBuilder));
                    builder.newPage();
                }

                reportBuilder.detail(builder);
                reportBuilder.setDataSource(new JREmptyDataSource(1));
                reportBuilder.setIgnorePagination(true);
                reportBuilder.setPageFormat(PageType.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
                reportBuilder.export(xlsExporter);
```

This code part using export.
I think  `builder.newPage();` line not working on server correctly.

Comment: Do you really `jasperReportBuilder.setIgnorePagination(true);` need this?

Comment: related, show different methods to control sheet and page break, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808741/how-to-export-to-multiple-sheets-in-excel-from-jasper-report. However its impossibile for us to reproduce this, so we can only guess and give tips not answer.

Comment: jasperReportBuilder.setIgnorePagination(true);   yes i need it. Without this code,table write in 2 page