# Succeeding pages of the crosstabs keeps on going to the next sheet, how do I make it into the same page?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using Jasper reports for my report generation module, now my dilemma is that whenever I generate a large crosstab, the first sheet shows only the first 30 records, succeeding records are placed to the second sheet named "page 2". Now what I want is that all records are placed into the first sheet regardless of how many they are, in regards to the columns,I am ok since I placed **ignoreWidth** to true.

The program did what I wanted before, I just placed a parameter in the Dataset query and re-compiled and somehow, I must have messed around the other options that made it like it currently is.

Comment: What exactly is your question?, are you only exporting to excel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export to multiple sheets in excel from jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808741/how-to-export-to-multiple-sheets-in-excel-from-jasper-report)

Comment: The above will show you several methods of controlling sheets / page break in excel. If it solves your problem consider to accept duplicate.