# Jasper Subreport in Different excel sheet isn't working

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using UBUNTU 14.04 os
also the version of my jasper studio is 5.6

I have one jasper report which containing 10 subReports. I want to export each report in different excel sheet. i'm trying to set proper alignment/segments in excel sheet so that i can do basic math operation on columns. my each subreport having multiple text field that causes segmentation problem in excel sheet. so i'm trying to export each subreport in each different sheet.

each subreport generate more than 1 pages(variable paging)

I have tried following ways to export xls in different sheet

1. first i did **ignorePagination to true** in main report as well as in each subreport then **added the page break element** after each subreport group in main report but pagination isn't working.
2. also tried: Set the property **net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination=apply  net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet=true
   but in this jasper studio applies this property once ie. after each restart jasper studio then at second execution it won't work**
3. also tired setting property:
   **net.sf.jasperreports.break.before.row=true
   and/or
   net.sf.jasperreports.break.after.row=true**
   added line element or blank static text field element after each subreport in subreport group. this isn't working for whole report. after applying these properties segmentation problem remain as it is.
4. even single **net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination=apply** in main report is also not working

**Here I'm Attaching my main.jrxml file's code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="POS_Billing_DailySalesReport_Type2" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="0" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="ddaeb9ca-aae7-4e61-9615-f25f60294adb">
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="jasperadmin"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/reports/SMARTORDER_REPORTS/SMARTORDER_BILLING_DSR/POS_Billing_DailySalesReport_Type2_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/SMARTORDER_REPORTS/SMARTORDER_BILLING_DSR/POS_Billing_DailySalesReport_Type2"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="POSConnection"/>
    <parameter name="fromDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="toDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="hotelName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="foodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,38,39,40,41"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="wineFoodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["14"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["17,37"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="liquorFoodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="companyId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select 1 from Dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="1" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <group name="DSR_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="60">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="1d4602df-49db-47be-84ad-ad22c861f068"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="hotelName">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{hotelName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <break>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="800" height="1" uuid="f022eaa4-5672-4140-8371-c9ba04435ea0"/>
                </break>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Cancel_Bill">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="60">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="718a14a1-286e-4c06-9f2b-9381b0c2a0e7"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="hotelName">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{hotelName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_Cancelled_Bill_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="NC_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="61">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="61" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="498c51ae-a361-4c0f-98e4-e05d973da8ff"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DailyNCReport_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Cancel_KOT_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="60">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="60" uuid="67c9d02f-cf0e-46f7-a072-31e94e5d0a60"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodcategoryId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_Cancelkot_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Cancel_BOT_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="60">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="60" uuid="be1c0cf4-a1c7-4cd7-b0cd-cff0b06fa124"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_Cancelbot_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Reprint_Bills">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="60">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="60" uuid="556e3c56-0683-41ed-98aa-01a9d888fdb0"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_reprintbill_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Summary_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="59">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="59" uuid="6cd3ce43-0edc-40ee-87e3-e499a178af60"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Summary_Subreport1_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="summarycancel_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="57">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="57" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="599a967c-7970-4285-bada-db370e285b5d"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Summary_Subreport3_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="SummaryNC_group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="51">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="51" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="8779a930-536d-4215-a99d-96ed55b9303e"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Summary_Subreport2_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="companyaccount_group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="60">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="8d2cde54-2c95-4912-8498-5edd50111ffd"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_CompanyNamewise_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Group1"/>
    <title>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
            <line direction="BottomUp">
                <reportElement x="-20" y="40" width="830" height="1" uuid="4338177c-bab1-4305-b8ee-495c03aa9e22">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="170" y="1" width="450" height="19" uuid="017a4739-0ade-4f16-9ddd-630f0fb0e075"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="16" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{hotelName}+" "+" Daily Sales Report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="170" y="19" width="450" height="17" uuid="f318ec8d-2fad-40d7-8f79-ee7fd4a1b7f5"/>
                <box rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["From :"+" "+$P{fromDate}+" "+"To :"+" "+$P{toDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="380" y="7" width="10" height="1" uuid="86d8e767-4246-4c32-9563-8e8fe3e67c06">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="3" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="2" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="33">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="733" y="7" width="67" height="14" uuid="6ee40ae8-4a38-4c44-8e29-20d584fd1a8d">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="3" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a">
                <reportElement x="-20" y="6" width="196" height="17" uuid="44854d7f-1c47-48c3-ae6d-8012bee7f985">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Printed On"+" "+new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="280" y="8" width="250" height="13" uuid="da6d6f7d-ad04-458d-aeec-a55ca5f5dae9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Eras Medium ITC" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["HotelName :"+$P{hotelName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="280" y="21" width="250" height="12" uuid="3ed7fd48-15c6-4af7-a7de-e59e2dcf554e">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Eras Medium ITC"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["From Date :"+$P{fromDate}+" "+"ToDate :"+$P{toDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="663" y="7" width="70" height="14" uuid="62487b63-096f-4278-8068-efcc5dcf9f7c"/>
                <box rightPadding="3"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**[Note: 1: i have added break element only for first sub report for testing purpose 2: isIgnorePagination=true is perfectly working in single report but not in main Report ie. main Report which contain sub reports ]**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export to multiple sheets in excel from jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808741/how-to-export-to-multiple-sheets-in-excel-from-jasper-report)

Comment: I have purposed a duplicate where you can see the different methods, let me know if you still have problems otherwise you can accept it.

Comment: yes i used those methods, i can't use 2nd because segmentation problem and 3rd because i'm using server. i'm using 1st way ie. ispagination=true and adding break element...but isignorepagination working in only one single report. i'm having one main report which include 10 sub report and i'm applying ignore isIgnorePagination=true for that report but still report is execution in multiple pages. (note: there is no other property i have set in main report and main report doesn't contain any query or fields. it is only having groups which have sub reports in it)