# specifying row limit for excel in jasper jrxml does not set the specified value

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a jrxml with Title and Detail band. I have to display Title band in another sheet when exported in excel so i set  `isTitleNewPage` to true.

However the details band has more than 50 row it divides detail band into number of sheet. Which I don't want . I want just two sheet in my generated excel Title and Detail.

in order to avoid multiple sheet of my records in detail band i set property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.max.rows.per.sheet` to 2000 . However still I am seeing my records in detail band splitted by 50 rows per sheet.

Can I achieve Title band in another sheet and Details band without pagination in another sheet.

Comment: has anyone tried giving limit on excel with option of "Title on new Page"

Comment: Related maybe duplicate [How to export to multiple sheets in excel from jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34808741/5292302), study it to understand how and when sheet is created in excel. You probably should use second solution explained in that answer.